# How to add a public method under another public method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing a website with a large library of JavaScript and jQuery code and I am trying to give it a more organized plugin-like structure. I [read an article](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/10/how-good-c-habits-can-encourage-bad-javascript-habits-part-1/) showing how to use a self-executing anonymous function to help with scope and it also allows your library to grow across files using the "window.namespace = window.namespace || {}" technique.

For example:

```
//Self-Executing Anonymous Function:
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {

    //Private Property
    var isHot = true;

    //Public Property
    skillet.ingredient = "eggs";

    //Public Method
    skillet.fry = function() {
        // do stuff...
    };

    //Private Method
    function addItem( item ) {
        // do stuff...
    }    
}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elijahmanor/MVNBz/22/)

My question is, how would I add a public method under skillet.fry(). So I could make a call to something like skillet.fry.cancel();

Or, if there is a better way to do this, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, you can add properties to functions (just write `skillet.fry.something = function() { ... }`), as Function is just another type of Object - and it can have additional properties defined, as other objects. But that would look quite awkward, in my opinion.

Comment: You have a `Adding New Functionality to the Skillet` section .. can't you add it there?

Comment: I can do what @raina77ow said, but it wouldn't allow me to define a variable in skillet.fry and still have access to it in skillet.fry.something() would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this. It would allow you to declare other variables (along with `that`) that would be available in the closure of `cancel()`.

```
skillet.fry = (function() {
    var that = {};

    that.cancel = function() {
        //...
    }

    return that;
})();
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to initialize `that`. If you initialize that to an empty (or any) object, it'll work. I'll update the code to reflect that.

Comment: For readability sake, would it be possible to add skillet.fry.cancel() outside of the skillet.fry function?

Comment: Yeah, you can do as raina77ow said and just do `skillet.fry.cancel = function(){}`. Functions are objects and can have properties like any other object.